# Spring 4 MVC REST (json response) - works on localhost, getting “Circular view path” on deployed host

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I've created a simple Spring-based web application, with a @RestController annotation for a class that one of its mappings returns a JSON response.

It works perfectly when I run it on localhost, but I get the following error when I try to call the url on the host it is deployed to (Bluemix). I got this exception on the localhost version, when I didn't define the class as @RestController (or it's parallel - @Controller & @ResponseBody):

`'Exception thrown by application class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering:205'
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [nextStep]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/nextStep] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)'`

These are my definitions:

RestController

```
@Controller
@ResponseBody
public class InterviewRESTController {

    @Autowired
    private transient InterviewFlowLogic interviewFlowLogic;

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
     private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();
    @RequestMapping("/nextStep")
       public ServiceRESTResponse nextStep(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name){
        return new ServiceRESTResponse(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                    String.format(template, name));
        }
}
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="il.intervyo.client.controller"></context:component-scan>

<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager"/>

<bean id="contentNegotiationManager"
    class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/xml" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Again, it is important to stress out that this code works when I run it localhost and the url returns the Json format response, but fails only on the deployed version - I saw the few questions-and-answers that are already on the site, non of them refers to this specific issue.

I'd gladly supply with any additional info needed (pom.xml, web.xml, etc.)